# Creating a .txt file with multiple echoed lines of text fails depending on the text

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I'm a casual coder trying to make a bat file that writes a txt file with multiple lines of text and it's not working for some reason.
My code so far for reference:

```
@echo off

(
  Echo;extends "res://Mod Data.gd"
  Echo;
  Echo;func_init():
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
) > "Output\custom.txt"
pause
```

(It might be unnecessary to put all the test stuff here but I put it there just incase that's what's causing it.)

When I try to run it, it closes instantly and doesn't work, but if I try to run it without "func_init():" it works like a charm.

Also, I made another bat file testing this out by only printing "func_init():" and that worked just fine as well, so I have no clue what this could be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Batch isn't smart enough to know that the `)` in `Echo;func_init():` *isn't* the end of the code block, so right now your script is aborting because it thinks the `:` is a syntax error. You can get around this by using the `^` character to escape the close parenthesis.

```
@echo off

(
  Echo;extends "res://Mod Data.gd"
  Echo;
  Echo;func_init(^):
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
  Echo;test
) >"Output\custom.txt"
pause
```

Comment: I've already rewritten that part in a way that works but thanks anyways! :)

Comment: Thought you might appreciate less writing :)

Comment: Ok, my way stopped working for some reason, I tried yours and it worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, it works if you format it like this:

```
@Echo Off

set "out=Output"

 >  "%out%\test.txt" Echo;extends "res://Mod Data.gd"
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;func_init():
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
 >> "%out%\test.txt" Echo;test
```

Comment: you only had to escape the `)` as `^)` in the code block because `cmd` sees it as a closing parenthesis for the block.

Comment: Well, yes, this works, but it reopens and closes the file for every single line to be written…